# How to access rows to access record in the XtraGrid CardView DevExpress

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a grid control set up with a master-detail relationship , however i want to know how i can access the detail view record or rows to perform Editing or Update information. I have tried this but it's not working, it returns 0 to the form:

```
void AddPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Paymentfrm payent = new Paymentfrm(Utils.Formtype.add, 0);
    payent.PaymentEvent += new EventHandler(RefreshingGrid);
    payent.PayentlabelsEvent += new EventHandler(RefresHlabels);

    gridView1.ViewCaption = " Lessee Payment ";
    CardView card = new CardView(DgPaymentYW);
    DgPaymentYW.LevelTree.Nodes.Add("LesseePayments", card);

    card.ViewCaption = " Lessee Payments";
    GetPayment.TotalPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(card.GetFocusedRowCellValue("TotalPrice"));


    payent.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code that does the editing and update?

Comment: The easiest way is to access the datasource and not the cards. You can cast the active card in your datasource type and access it.